# Is this Fitted vs Observed diagnostic plot strange?

Tags: r, regression, residuals, fitting, diagnostic

I am running a linear regression model in R with generalized least squares `gls()` on my data to fix residuals with unequal variance. I seem to have achieved this; however, I have a fitted vs observed diagnostic plot I am having trouble interpreting. Is it showing my model is not a good fit? If so, are there better model alternatives?

```
gls3 <- gls(value ~ Status + Time + Treatment + Status*Time, data=marker.NO.NS,
                      weights = varIdent(form = ~1|Status*Time))

residplot(gls3, slope = FALSE, id = FALSE, newwd=FALSE, ask=FALSE)
```

[image: Diagnostic Plots]

```
summary(gls3)
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: value ~ Status + Time + Treatment + Status * Time 
  Data: marker.NO.NS 
        AIC       BIC   logLik
  -406.9053 -376.1025 216.4527

Variance function:
 Structure: Different standard deviations per stratum
 Formula: ~1 | Status * Time 
 Parameter estimates:
    Clinical*Time1    Clinical*Time2  Subclinical*Time1 Subclinical*Time2      Control*Time1 
         1.000000          0.211813          2.909308          1.826647          3.721676 
    Control*Time2 
         2.180214 

Coefficients:
                                 Value   Std.Error   t-value p-value
(Intercept)                  0.9589252 0.009412548 101.87732  0.0000
StatusSubclinical           -0.0265714 0.011929333  -2.22740  0.0288
StatusClinical               0.0201188 0.009710017   2.07197  0.0415
Time2                        0.0069188 0.010799297   0.64067  0.5236
Treatment1                   0.0002925 0.001029454   0.28415  0.7770
StatusSubclinical:Time2      0.0360098 0.013852127   2.59958  0.0111
StatusClinical:Time2         0.0106766 0.011084521   0.96320  0.3384

 Correlation: 
                            (Intr) SttsSb SttsCl Tm2    Trt1   SS:T2
StatusSubclinical           -0.787                                   
StatusClinical              -0.966  0.763                            
Time2                       -0.869  0.686  0.842                     
Treatment1                  -0.055  0.000 -0.004 -0.003              
StatusSubclinical:Time2      0.677 -0.861 -0.657 -0.780  0.002       
StatusClinical:Time2         0.846 -0.668 -0.876 -0.974  0.006  0.760

Standardized residuals:
       Min         Q1        Med         Q3        Max 
-2.6792397 -0.6361520  0.1764471  0.6780872  2.1868624 

Residual standard error: 0.009448922 
Degrees of freedom: 86 total; 79 residual
```

Comment: Please tell us what leads you to suppose there is anything "strange" about this output.

Comment: All the fitted vs observed diagnostic plots I have seen interpreted on online guides say the data points should fall very close to the line to be considered a good fit. I have yet to see one with horizontal lines like that and I'm not sure what it means, if anything.

Comment: To which "horizontal line" do you refer?  You can read about many examples here by searching for [regression diagnostic plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+diagnostic+plot).

Comment: Looks like the lines correspond to predicted values in each of the six strata.